# How do I include a validates_confrmation_of in a Module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to include

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

in a module but i keep getting errors like:

"undefined method `validates_confirmation_of' for Password::ClassMethods:Module"

Not sure how I can make it work.

thanks

Comment: Now if only we had what the error was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `validates_confirmation_of` in the module itself because the module's code is executed when it is created. Instead, you want to call the validation method when the module is included in the ActiveRecord model, like so:

```
module Password::ClassMethods
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:validates_confirmation_of, :password)
  end
end
```